# How to add domain user to existing shared folder shared tab (permissions) using command line?

Tags: command-line, permissions, network-shares, windows-server-2008

I have multiple shared folders on server (**windows server 2008**) which are shared for multiple users. 
My problem is I want to add give access of few folders to newly created domain user. 
Now there are two things that I have noticed
**1. Security tab**: I am able to add user to to that red line using following command:

```
icacls d:\TestFolder /grant:r "username":(OI)(CI)F /T
```

and I can remove user from that list by using following command:

```
icacls  d:\TestFolder  /remove:g Administrator /T
```

[image: Security tab]

**2. Sharing tab**: Not able to add here.
By using above command, user is not get added to sharing tab.
So, I tried following command:

```
net share Docs=d:\TestFolder /grant:username=F
```

But, it works only first time. That is to share folder first time not for existing shared folder.
[image]

**Note:** The image shows that folder has access to everyone, but this is just testing folder image, **not from actual server**. So the folder will **not have access to everyone**.

Apart from above command I tried with [SubInACL.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=23510):

```
subinacl /verbose=1 /share d:\TestFolder /grant=username=f
```

But this command also add user to security tab not in sharing tab.
Please help me to find the command or let me know if it is possible or not using command line.

Comment: Why not use Everyone for the share and limit by using NTFS permissions?

Comment: @Seth as I have added **Note**, the image is not from the server. That everyone will not be there on server.

Comment: Yes, but as e. g. detailed in this [Technet article on Share and NTFS Permissions on a File Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178(v=ws.11).aspx) NTFS permissions are the "more powerful" ones. You could simply restrict normal users on the NTFS level and "ignore" the share permissions.

Comment: @Seth thanks for sharing link. Still I am looking for the answer, As I want it in command line.